# How to handle an asynchronous callback in a synchronous function call?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, callback, objective-c-blocks

I am having a method which asynchronously returns an object (e.g. UserProfile) in a callback.

Based on this UserProfile object, some code computes whether a `UITableViewCell` is editable or not:

I created the following code, but it's unfortunately not working.

```
- (BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView canEditRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{        
    Entry *entry = [[self.feed entries] objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]];
    typedef BOOL (^BOOLBlock)(id);

    BOOLBlock bar = ^BOOL (id p) {
        if (p) {
            UserProfile *user = (UserProfile *) p;
            NSEnumerator *e = [[entry authors] objectEnumerator];
            id object;
            while (object = [e nextObject]) {
                if ([[object name] isEqualToString:[[[user authors] objectAtIndex:0] name]])
                    return TRUE;
            }
            return FALSE;
        } 
        else {
            return FALSE;
        }
    };

    [[APPContentManager classInstance] userProfile:bar];    
}
```

At the last line, it says **Incompatible block pointer types sending**

```
'__strong BOOLBlock' (aka 'BOOL (^__strong)(__strong id)') to parameter of type 'void (^)(UserProfile *__strong)'
```

---

### APPContentManager.h

```
-(void)userProfile:(void (^)(UserProfile *user))callback;
```

Comment: It appears that your AppContentManager userProfile method does not expect a block with a boolean return value.

Comment: Additionally, you should be aware of the fact that the delegate method canEditRowAtIndexPath is to return a boolean immediately and not asynchronously. You should go back to the data modelling board and see if you can keep that needed information at hand as soon as it is needed (e.g. by prepopulating the userProfile model with that value).

Comment: You are also not returning any value in that method.

Comment: Till, thanks for your quick response. 1.) I added the signature of the method in question. You are right, in it's current implementation, it doesn't expect a boolean return value. Is there a way to change the code in canEditRowAtIndexPath rather than in userProfile? 2.) Thanks for the hint. Actually, UserProfile is cached in APPContentManager, so it's returned immediately.

Comment: See @NoahWitherspoon solution - though I personally would go in a different direction and simply add a method to the model class (userProfile) that lets me know if that profile may be edited. That way you dont need to use a semaphore - semaphores are a rather heavy weapon...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `-userProfile:` method isn’t expecting your BOOLBlock type—it’s not responsible for returning anything. You want to use a semaphore here, though you should keep in mind Till’s comments about the expected synchronicity of `-tableView:canEditRowAtIndexPath:`—if your userProfile: method is going to take a while, you should definitely be precaching this editability information.

```
- (BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView canEditRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {        
    Entry *entry = [[self.feed entries] objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]];
    dispatch_semaphore_t sema = dispatch_semaphore_create(0);
    __block BOOL foundAuthor = NO;

    [[APPContentManager classInstance] userProfile:^(UserProfile *user) {
        NSEnumerator *e = [[entry authors] objectEnumerator];
        id object;
        while (object = [e nextObject]) {
            if ([[object name] isEqualToString:[[[user authors] objectAtIndex:0] name]]) {
                foundAuthor = YES;
                break;
            }
        }
        dispatch_semaphore_signal(sema);
    }];
    dispatch_semaphore_wait(sema, DISPATCH_TIME_FOREVER);
    dispatch_release(sema);

    return foundAuthor;
}
```

Comment: It will. I’m assuming that the `-userProfile:` method uses a block for convenience rather than because it’ll take a while to run.

Comment: Got it, I was assuming that the author actually used asynchronous data retrieval in the background of that userProfile method call. So to spell it out clear, do not use this suggestion if the userProfile call actually needs time to complete (e.g. by doing some web-fetches). Else, the watchdog hounds will bite you ;)

Comment: Yes, userProfile uses a block for convenience when it's called in canEditRowAtIndexPath. It's only called asynchronously one time at some earlier state of the app life cycle, when the user logs in, to be more precise.

Comment: Never worked with semaphores on iOS before, getting an (lldb) exception at line "dispatch_release(sema);" when using the proposed code above.

Comment: Shouldn't it be dispatch_semaphore_create(0)? You'd have to call wait twice if you create it using 1.